# Manipulate HTML with HAproxy and Lua

Tags: html, lua, haproxy

I am using a software that has some hard coded configuration and I would like to change that on the fly, in order to load a different geojson. In nginx I would use

```
sub_filter '"map":"old_map.geojson"' '"map":"new_map.geojson"'
```

In HAproxy I imagine I could be able to achieve so using Lua, but I haven't found any example. Do you know if it is possible? and if yes how? So far I have learned how to load Lua services, but I haven't found documentation on how to manipulate the text, like:

```
string.gsub(HTML, '"map":"old_map.geojson"', '"map":"new_map.geojson"')
```

Comment: Is this link helpfull? https://www.arpalert.org/haproxy-rewrite-body.html

Comment: Thanks @Aleksandar it was to late at night probably and, while reading lot of pages from that site, I did not see that :O!